# Strange 'X' character being echoed out with MYSQL result?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to login a user using the following code below.

The code seems to be working and the user is logged in perfectly fine. However, when I ask it to echo out my MYSQL result with the user's ID (which is a number ONLY), i get the following result:

```
x 111
```

The letter x is nowhere to be found in my database and I do am trying to use this:

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $row['user_id']);
```

to get rid of the x but its not working and the letter x remains.

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

```
<?php  ob_start();
require 'connect.php'; 
if(!isset($_SESSION)) { 
    session_start(); }

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // username and password sent from form 

        $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['username']);
        $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['password']); 

        $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM user_data WHERE username = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        //$active = $row['loggedIn'];

        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

        if($count == 1) {
            if (!isset($_SESSION["myusername"])) {

                $_SESSION['login_user'] = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $row['user_id']);
                 $res = $_SESSION['login_user'];
                 $sql = "UPDATE user_data SET loggedIn='True' WHERE username = '$myusername'";
                 echo $res;
                 //header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
                 die;

            }else {
                echo "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
        }
    } 
}
?>

<script>
    if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
        window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
    }
</script>




<div class="form">
<h1>Log In</h1>
<form action="" method="post" name="login">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="lg_box" required />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="lg_box"required />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<p>Not registered yet? <a href='registration.php'>Register Here</a></p>
</div>


<style>

    .lg_box {
        width:100%;
        height:35px;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        margin-top:10px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding:10px;
        margin-bottom:20px;


    }    
</style>
```

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: try print_r($row) and check if its there. probably its somewhere in your html .

Comment: ___Unrelated Point___ After this line `$sql = "UPDATE user_data SET loggedIn='True' WHERE username = '$myusername'";` you dont actually run that query anywhere

Comment: Get rid of the code you are using to try and fix an issue that is not there. Look elsewhere for your X

Comment: If the x is not in this file, maybe it's in one you're bringing in with include. For example connect.php